# Angular UI bootstrap modal redirect after function using location.path

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, routes, angular-ui-bootstrap

After a user clicks okay in this modal, it should take them to another page. I have the routing in my app.js, my function in my controller, and my modal view, but it just keeps on taking the user to '#/home' and no where else. Not sure why this is going on or what to do to fix it. Any ideas?

My code:

Modal in view:

```
<!-- Recur Confirm Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="recurConfirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="recurConfirm" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <p>Congratulations! Your recurring claim has been submitted and will be reviewed by our customer service team.  We’ll contact you if we have any questions or concerns with your submission. If you have questions about your submission, please contact our customer service team at (800) 669-3539 or <a class="naviaLink" href="mailto:customerservice@naviabenefits.com">customerservice@naviabenefits.com</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay" ng-click="recurOkay()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

My controller function (this modal is triggered when the user saves data and then it does the redirect):

```
$scope.recurOkay = function() {
    $('#recurConfirm').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();   
    $location.path('/#/pptHome');
};
```

And my route is pretty standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$location.path` method accept URL `string` only, that string shouldn't have `#` in it. Basically this method will append given `string` after `#` in the `URL`.

So in your case `$location.path('/#/pptHome');` after executing it, it redirect to the URL `http://localhost/#/#/pptHome` which doesn't recognize by route engine  and it redirects to fallback URL.

To solve the issue do following.

```
$location.path('/pptHome'); //will redirect to `/#/pptHome`
```